# Igraph makevars will not link to static library, i can use data structures but cannot functions while importing igraph c++ library

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, igraph

I am trying to install my C++ igraph library from https://github.com/igraph/igraph to visual studio code using the [following method](https://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Installation.html) this is my makefile made according to this [link](https://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Tutorial.html).

```
CXX = g++
CXX_FLAGS = -std=c++17 -O3 -march=native -DNDEBUG


LIB = -Llib
INC = -Iinclude

.PHONY: all
all: a.out

a.out: main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) $(INC) $(LIB) -ligraph -lm -lstdc++ -lgomp -lpthread -o $@ main.cpp
    
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm a.out
```

The compiler will always return something like:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -march=native -DNDEBUG -Iinclude -Llib -ligraph -lm -lstdc++ -lgomp -lpthread -o a.out main.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccqJLfvi.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x9): undefined reference to `igraph_rng_default'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x16): undefined reference to `igraph_rng_seed'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:12: a.out] Error 1
```

If i only want to use data structures such as igraph_t graph* it will work, but if i try to call fucntion it will return error and will not generate a.out file. It would be incredablly good if someone would be able to explain why this happens cuz it really got on my nerve right now.

Comment: The igraph library is not linked correctly. It is hard to tell why without more information about what you did _exactly_ (including how and where you installed igraph and a short self-contained example). Make sure that you give the correct path to the location where igraph was installed. I would actually recommend using CMake to build your own program as it takes care of the intricacies of linking to igraph.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i have solved it already by changing the argument order, also this issue commes(primarly) from R studio, where i have the same isuess as here and i need it only for personal use as i am only writting function for different enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instructions [in the documentation](https://igraph.org/c/html/latest/) to set up your package to link to igraph.

- Instructions to install igraph: https://igraph.org/c/html/latest/igraph-Installation.html Note that you must both *build* and *install* the package. Make a note of the location you used to install it to (the value of `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`)
- Instructions on compiling your first igraph program: https://igraph.org/c/html/latest/igraph-Tutorial.html Unless you are already comfortable with writing C programs and linking them to external libraries, I *strongly* recommend that you use CMake to set up your project, as described in the linked tutorial. CMake works the same way on all platforms (Windows/macOS/Linux) and will automatically figure out how to link your program to igraph correctly. When configuring your project, be sure to set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to the location where you installed igraph earlier.